# Trying to use Screenshot Code using windows but on a Macbook But it is only capturing the top left of the screen C#

Tags: c#, windows, macos

All im trying to do is take a screenshot of my screen so that I can use it else where. Its only capturing the top left of the screen. Ive done heavy debugging and found the problem is that since im running windows on a mac the values for the size of the screen is wrong and therefore only caputeing a portion of the screen.
This is my testing code, all i need is for a caputre of the whole screen, or alternitively allow me the capture specific parts of the screen, like the middle.

```
 var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                       Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                       PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

 var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

 gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
 CurrentSS = bmpScreenshot;
 pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenshot;
```

And this is what it captures:

[image: Image of Form]

Comment: How are you running Windows on macOS? Boot camp? Parallels? A VM? Remote desktop?

Comment: I believe it is boot camp, The only issue is the like I say the Primary screen size seems to be wrong

Comment: Could it be [DPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)?

Comment: @stuartd Yeah that could be the case, Ill try it out, Ill try and then come back to you on that :)

Comment: @stuartd That was the problem, I fixed it by just lowering the resolution of my monitor, the only problem now is surprisingly enough the image is a low resolution, hopefully it wont be a problem but I guess ill get to that when I get to it